# How to use a condition from one list to find a value from a different list

Tags: python, zip

I have two lists:

```
lista = [0,5,0,5,0,5]
listb = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Is there a way that when a value of `lista` is `5`, it finds it in the corresponding place in `listb` so the letters `'b','d','f'` are the outcome?

I thought about using `zip` to get it, but I can't figure out how to apply the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via a conditional list comprehension:

```
lista = [0,5,0,5,0,5]
listb = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
print ([listb[i] for i,a in enumerate(lista) if a == 5])
```

Comment: When I typed it in I got an error of 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: Just tested it in both languages.  It works fine.  Make sure just to copy and paste the whole thing and try that first.  Does that work? What version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.3.2 but yeah it works sorry, was trying it in the shell first my bad....

Answer (score 2):

You can also use numpy. It's going to be much faster if your dataset is huge.

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.asarray([0,5,0,5,0,5])
listb = np.asarray(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
listb[lista==5]
```